How to add a user to a github team, via email address?
I am trying to use the gh cli to add a github user to a github team membership via email address.
The user is already a member of the parent github organization.
I can do this via the web ui and it works successfully

When I try to do it via the api, I get error messages.
What can I do to recreate that web ui functionality via command line?
Ive tried with the legacy api and it doesnt work
TEAM_ID=$(gh api /orgs/${{ github.repository_owner }}/teams/${TEAM_SLUG} --jq '.id')

gh api \
--method PUT \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
/teams/${TEAM_ID}/members/${username}


 gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/teams/members#add-team-member-legacy","status":"404"}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

and with the latest api and it doesnt work
gh api \
  --method PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /orgs/${{ github.repository_owner }}/teams/${TEAM_SLUG}/memberships/$username \
  -f "role=member"


gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/teams/members#add-or-update-team-membership-for-a-user","status":"404"}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have tried using the org invite route, but receive an error because the user is already an org member
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /orgs/${{ github.repository_owner }}/invitations \
  -f "email=$username" -f "role=direct_member" -F "team_ids[]=$TEAM_ID"


gh: Validation Failed (HTTP 422)
{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"OrganizationInvitation","code":"unprocessable","field":"data","message":"A user with this email addresss is already a part of this organization"}],"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/orgs/members#create-an-organization-invitation","status":"422"}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


Please include the full error message as text in the body of your question for each of the attempts you’ve made - it makes it much easier for potential answerers to help you

@esqew made the change TIA

Is $username the email address? And what permissions does your script have?

@BenjaminW. $username is a place holder for a persons email address, the script has read write at the org level for "Members"( Organization members and teams. )

If you are on GitHub Enterprise, you could convert the email address to the GitHub login.
